# Alternative for Exchange 2007 mail and calender sync and shared + public calenders and folders?

Tags: software-recommendation, ms-exchange

I am trying to replace my Windows 7 system with a working Ubuntu system but I am running into issues with several software being used at work. Could anyone please advise alternatives for the following software / tools?

1. Exchange 2007 mail & calendar sync (
   Evolution is too slow to load mails
   and calendar)
2. shared & public calendars and
   folders

Comment: I second Jorge's request. Please split these into separate questions. The Stack Exchange system can't help the best answers "bubble to the top" when you ask more than one question at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 years I have found the perfect solution. Mozilla Thunderbird 17 with Exquilla for Microsoft Exchange and Exchange EWS Provider 3.2.
I am able to access MS Exchange Emails, Addressbook, calendar and shared calendars in public folders.

Tested on Ubuntu 13.04

No need to switch on the VM anymore! :)

**UPDATE**Tested on Ubuntu 14.04**With 2 MS Exchange accounts.

There are two options avaialble to Ubuntu users for accessing MS EXchange email and calendar

1. Mozilla Thunderbird + Exquilla Plugin - THe plugin is a shareware , free for first 3 months then $10 / year
2. Evolution + Evolution-EWS/Evolution-Mapi - This is free and works perfectly with MS Exchange 2007 and 2010 . Syncs, mail, contacts, GAL, calendar and public calendars.  The best part is that Evolution not slow anymore, nor does it crash so often.

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird with lightning calendar will work with Microsoft Exchange just fine.

```
sudo apt-get install thunderbird
```

then install the Lightning extension

Comment: Thunderbird cannot retrieve emails from exchange server unless pop/imap is enabled . A big drawback!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/) as email client, for the rest I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Although Evolution with be a natural answer you may try "Zimbra Desktop", you must donwload it directly from http://www.zimbra.com since it is not in the repositories.

But for the folders part I am not sure.